# Goodwillie Calculus

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories, derived-functors

If $F$ is a homotopy functor of spaces with values on spaces or spectra, and $P_nF$ is its associate Taylor tower, do I have a connection between $cr_n(P_nF)$ and $cr_nF$.

Here $cr_n$ denotes the $n^{th}$ cross effect

Comment: see:  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.01930.pdf

Comment: Could you choose a more specific title for your question?

Comment: Yes. That's what section 6 of my Calculus 3 paper is all about. The symmetric multilinear functor $cr_nP_nF$ (which is the same as $cr_nD_nF$ and therefore according to section 3 and in the unstable case section 2 contains enough information to determine $D_nF$) coincides with the ''multilinearization'' of the ''multi-reduced'' symmetric functor $cr_nF$.